# want to insert multiple values on select

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select multiple options from list and then want to insert those values in an input field. What I have done so far.

HTML:

```
  <div class="input-container">
    <label>preffered country</label>
       <div class="dropdown-container-multiple">
          <input type="text" name="pc" placeholder="please select" required />
            <span></span>
              <ul name="country" class="multiple">
                <li>I don't know</li>
                <li>Italy</li>
                <li>Spain</li>
                <li>Switzerland</li>
                <li>Turkey</li>
              </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.dropdown-container-multiple ul li').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $(this).parent('ul').parent('.dropdown-container-multiple').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

This is doing good for single value option but I tried what I knew but it didn't work for multiple selection

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to concatenate to the old value, not just replace it.

```
$('.dropdown-container-multiple ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).parent('ul').parent('.dropdown-container-multiple').find('input').val(function(i, oldval) {
        return oldval == '' ? text : oldval + " " + text;
    });
});
```

To be able to add and remove items from the input, join all the texts from the `active` elements.

```
$('.dropdown-container-multiple ul li').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var texts = $(".dropdown-container-multiple ul li.active").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(" ");
    $(this).parent('ul').parent('.dropdown-container-multiple').find('input').val(texts);
});
```

Comment: Function (A){Return V(This,Function(A){Return Void 0===A?M.Text(This):This.Empty().Append((This[0]&&This[0].OwnerDocument||Y).CreateTextNode(A))},Null,A,Arguments.Length)}

Comment: had a typo, I left out the `()` after `.text`.

Comment: work like charm and just one last thing can we delete the text which already selected and user click that again like toggle function?

Comment: Why don't you just use a real `<select multiple>`?

Comment: You can use `oldval.indexOf(text) > -1)` to test if the selected text is already in there, and `oldval.replace(text, '')` to remove it.

Comment: This is custom build dropdown list which have some more functionality too that's why unable to use select tag

Comment: Another way would be to toggle a `selected` class on the `<li>` when you click on it. Then join the text from all the selected ones and put it into the value.

Comment: can you please edit your above code to show me how you do it sorry for asking too much but I know jquery very little

Comment: I already toggle a class 'active' to show selection if you check the code.

Comment: yes I am learning jquery that's why I did what I learn till now I feel something difficult that's why I asked from expert likes you.

Comment: There's a difference between learning and getting other people to do it for you. You learn programming by trying to figure it out yourself, not by copying.

Comment: @Barmar , you are genius  and nice job!

Comment: @Barmar , why not use parents instead of parent?

Comment: @ehsan Why do you need to find all the parents instead of just one?

Comment: @Barmar , `parents('.dropdown-container-multiple')` is best or `.parent('ul').parent('.dropdown-container-multiple')` ?

Comment: Actually, `.closest('.dropdown-container-multiple')` is what I would probably use. But it's unrelated to the question so I didn't change it.

Comment: your meaning is that `parents'  find all parents then filter  `.dropdown-container-multiple` ?

Comment: `.parents('.dropdown-container-multiple')` returns all ancestors with the class, `.closest('.dropdown-container-multiple')` stops when it finds the first one.